# Horizontal scrollbar in vaadin is not appearing

Tags: layout, vaadin, horizontal-scrolling

I try to make vaadin view add horizontal scrollbar, but it have no any result. Could you, please, help me. Here is full code of my view:

```
public class TestView extends CssLayout implements View {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void init() {
    Layout content = new VerticalLayout();
    content.setSizeFull();
    addComponent(content);

    // add content to make the scrollbar appear
    HorizontalLayout rightLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        rightLayout.addComponent(new Button("Button " + i));
    }

    Panel rightPanel = new Panel(rightLayout);
    rightPanel.setSizeFull();

    content.addComponent(rightPanel);
}

public TestView() {
    super();
    init();
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Please check the size of the outer CssLayout. Its size must not be undefined. It's important that components with relative size (e.g. 100%) are in layouts with fixed or relative but not undefined size. Inside the Panel use fixed or undefined size, so that the content can be larger than the Panel and the scrollbar appears.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. It works, but for appearing of scrollbar (just horizontal) I need to refresh page. Is there any way to add this scrollbar dynamicaly? I've add such part:    setWidth(UI.getCurrent().getPage().getBrowserWindowWidth(), Unit.PIXELS);
  setHeight(UI.getCurrent().getPage().getBrowserWindowHeight() - 38, Unit.PIXELS);

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably have Extended VerticalLayout rather than CSSLayout, So something like this:

```
public class TestView extends VerticalLayout implements View {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void init() {
    setSizeFull();

    // add content to make the scrollbar appear
    HorizontalLayout rightLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        rightLayout.addComponent(new Button("Button " + i));
    }

    Panel rightPanel = new Panel(rightLayout);
    rightPanel.setSizeFull();

    addComponent(rightPanel);
}

public TestView() {
    super();
    init();
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've add listener and it work fine:

```
Page.getCurrent().addBrowserWindowResizeListener(event -> {
        setWidth(UI.getCurrent().getPage().getBrowserWindowWidth(), Unit.PIXELS);
        setHeight(UI.getCurrent().getPage().getBrowserWindowHeight(), Unit.PIXELS);
    });
```